# Android Screen Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Good Day,

Im developing an app, which has multiple tabs that was created using ViewPager and each tab is a fragment.

May I ask, how can I split the fragment into two layout? one is for My Profile and the other half is for list view.

[Here is the Screenshot layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1we9.png)

Comment: This is not a **code for me service**. First try something and let us know where you are having problem..!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with fragments, but I think you can use a layout inflater to inflate your views.

So you just create two new XML layout files and build your UI there. Let's call them `profile` and `listview`.

In `onCreate` of your fragment, get your fragment's root view group. Then, get a layout inflater:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.getActivity());
View profileView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, null, false);
View listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null, false);

// You should position profileView and listView in the right place here

yourFragmentsRootView.addView(profileView);
yourFragmentsRootView.addView(listView);
```

Basically what I am doing here is just inflating some views from layout files and add the inflated view to the fragment's layout.

Answer (score 0):

in a fragment their is a method called onCreateView which is the equivalent of an Activity's onCreate. you need to declare a View variable. you will use it as the rootView and return its value at the end of the onCreateView. you also need to declare the components you use in the fragment layout. then initialize those components inside the onCreateView method. like this(i don't know what MY PROFILE is so i'll just assume its a relativelayout)

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
    RelativeLayout myProfile;
    ListView lv;
    View rootView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lyt, container, false);
        myProfile = (RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.myProfileId);
        lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvId);

        //if you need to use context in a fragment, use getActivity(). its what i use. this well only show your fragment. to add listener, its the same as adding one on an activity.
        return rootView;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the layout XML of your fragment turn the root into a `LinearLayout` with `orientation` vertical.

Add a Relative layout and ListView inside it like so.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!-- add the elements of your profile here -->

    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```